# How can i get the date from the EditText and then store it in database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i am using an edittext for the user input in which user entered his Date of birth. The input type of the edittext is Date and then i am passing that date to a variable. That date is not passed to that variable and giving some error.

The code i am using is below

```
Edit dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy/MM/dd" );
    String dob_var=sdf.format(dob.getText());
    //dob_var=dob.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(dob_var);
```

After that i want to pass that date in database so what is the type require to store that date in database.
My logcat is:

```
    04-05 16:54:22.060: D/AndroidRuntime(3104): Shutting down VM
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foursquaregame.in/com.foursquaregame.in.Astro_talk}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:373)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:133)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at com.foursquaregame.in.Astro_talk.onCreate(Astro_talk.java:32)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-05 16:54:22.146: E/AndroidRuntime(3104):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is your error?? post here

Comment: application is crashed when i move on that activity which contain this code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally got it,

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Make sure user insert date into edittext in this format.

Date dateObject;

try{
String dob_var=(tx.getText().toString());

dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);

date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);
time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mmaa").format(dateObject);
}

catch (java.text.ParseException e) 
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("E11111111111", e.toString());
    }

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), date + time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hope this will help you...

Thanks...

Answer (score 7):

First you need to convert your edittext's string into date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date dob_var = sdf.parse(dob.getText());
```

now convert **dob_var** into sqlite standard date string:

```
DateFormat dateFormatISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String strDob = dateFormatISO8601.format(dob_var);

/* save strDob into database */
```

Comment: The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Editable) That error arises when i try to parse dob

Comment: then you need to check if your *dob* is not null. Use it like this: `if(!TexUtils.isEmpty(dob.getText()){ /* do something */ }`

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
 String dob_var=sdf.format(dob.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: still getting the same problem. My app is crashed when i move on the activity which contain this code