# add android calendar events using java

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Hi I am trying to add event to android calendar. I am new to android development. Please help me how can I add events to android calendar. Here is my code which does not work. When I run it, it gives me a message  "The application calendar (process com.something.something) has stopped unexpectedly"and has this button "Force to stop". Here is my code

```
package com.zafar.calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Calendar extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{"_id", "displayname"}, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // Get calendars name
    String calendarNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    // Get calendars id
    int[] calendarId = new int[cursor.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < calendarNames.length; i++)
    {
             calendarId[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
             calendarNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
             cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    ContentValues contentEvent = new ContentValues();
     contentEvent.put("calendar_id", 1);
     contentEvent.put("title", "Wedding");
     contentEvent.put("eventLocation", "New York");
     contentEvent.put("dtstart","1335432431000");
     contentEvent.put("dtend","1335436031000");

     Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
     getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, contentEvent);

}
}
```

**Update**
Here is my menifest file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Calendar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
</application>
```

**Logcat**

I am new to android development. I do not know logcat exactly. I ran logcat commmand on command prompt and I got this

```
    04-28 09:16:57.956: D/AndroidRuntime(333): Shutting down VM
04-28 09:16:57.956: W/dalvikvm(333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zafar.calendar/com.zafar.calendar.Calendar}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at com.zafar.calendar.Calendar.onCreate(Calendar.java:51)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-28 09:16:57.975: E/AndroidRuntime(333):  ... 11 more
04-28 09:21:58.095: I/Process(333): Sending signal. PID: 333 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Did you give ``<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />`` into your manifest file??

Comment: Yes I use permissions. you can see the menifest file now. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars") change to Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/Calendars")

Comment: Same problem after changeing Uri.parse

Comment: What is your Line 51 of your Calendar.java??

Comment: I updated my Calendar.java above. It has 47 lines of code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10639/discussion-between-never-quit-and-al0ne-evenings)

Comment: hello @x4ph4r Could you tell how you have configured you layout file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mistake in your code:

1. `new String[]{"calendar_id", "displayname"}, null, null, null);`

There is no column exists name calendar_id in Calendar database. Correct is **_id** not calendar_id. So it will be new String[]{"**_id**", "displayname"}, null, null, null);

And see this reference. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310258 And http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/calendar

**EDIT**

For inserting new event, 3 values are required. Calendar_id, EventStartTime And EventEndTime. Without these values you cannot insert new event. EventStartTime and EventEndTime need into epoch format.

For normal date to epoch date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687502/1160207 
For epoch to normal date: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028980/1160207

Here is the code that perfectly working to me.

```
Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{"_id", "displayname"}, null, null, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
// Get calendars name
String calendarNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];
// Get calendars id
int[] calendarId = new int[cursor.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < calendarNames.length; i++)
{
         calendarId[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
         calendarNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
         cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();

ContentValues contentEvent = new ContentValues();
 contentEvent.put("calendar_id", 1);
 contentEvent.put("title", "Wedding");
 contentEvent.put("eventLocation", "New York");                
 contentEvent.put("dtstart","1335432431000");
 contentEvent.put("dtend","1335436031000");


 Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
 getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, contentEvent);
```

Hope this will help you. And don't forget to accept it if it is helpful to you.

Thanks...

Comment: I followed both of your references but it is still the same error. I also changed calender_id to _id but it didnt solve the problem.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can find logcat at Window->Show View->LogCat. Here you can see your errors.

Comment: After editing my code according to what you mentioned. But still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If there are specific calendar applications you wish to integrate with, contact their developers and determine if they offer an API. So, for example, the Calendar application from the Android open source project, that Mayra cites, offers no documented and supported APIs. Google has even explicitly told developers to not use the techniques outlined in the tutorial Mayra cites.

Another option is for you to add events to the Internet calendar in question. For example, the best way to add events to the Calendar application from the Android open source project is to add the event to the user's Google Calendar via the appropriate GData APIs.