# Adding and displaying Events in Android Phone calendar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-calendar

I want to add and display events stored in builtin calender of my Android device. I have few questions

1.Do all phones have built in calendars?

2.How to add and display in the calendar events inside my application?

Comment: use pickers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Check out this post.I think you might find something useful here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361831/add-android-calendar-events-using-java