# Android - Get time from EditText inputType="time"

Tags: android

I have `EditText` in my XML file:

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/etExitHour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:hint="exit hour"/>
```

How can I get the time that the user enters?

Comment: You need SimpleDateFormat Take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028211/how-can-i-get-the-date-from-the-edittext-and-then-store-it-in-database-in-androi

Comment: which formate ???? hh:mm:ss ??

Comment: are you like to get edit text text. that is time

Comment: I have answered your question below...just make time format as you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = editText.getText().toString();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = formatter.parse(str);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need Time not Date

Comment: Date class has a method date.getTime() which returns you the time in long

Comment: @NomNom Check my answer above it will calculate both time & date.

Comment: hahah @Suhas arn't you doing the same thing which i have done

Comment: Nitesh, Suhas Thanks,I have another editText for the date,There is a way to get just the time?

Comment: @nomnom SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss") will formate your input to hh:mm:ss where hh is for hours mm is for minutes and ss is for seconds. it is returning the time in hh:mm:ss formate as you required.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
EditText etExitHouret = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etExitHour);        

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Make sure user insert date into edittext in this format.

Date dateObject;    
String date;
String time;

try {
    String dob_var=(etExitHouret.getText().toString());

    dateObject = formatter.parse(dob_var);

    date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);
    time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mmaa").format(dateObject);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), date + time, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 
catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I take the time (string) and convert him to time?

Answer (score 0):

this below code will help you

```
String string = editText.getText().toString();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
Date date = formatter.parse(string);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need Time not Date